# Count number of neurons and weights in a Caffe solution

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe

I have a Caffe project I have acquired with a `prototxt` model description and a `caffemodel` tuned parameter file (about 16 Mb in size). Is there an easy way to find out how many neurons and weights there is in the model, either from static analysis or at runtime?

I can visualise the `prototxt` file in [Netscope](https://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/editor), but there's 24 convolution layers and seven pooling layers, so I don't really know where to start counting from. I also saw [this Google Groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/digits-users/ZMK-e6aJxQ8), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can count the weight parameters from the prototxt file, without even looking at the caffemodel. For a convolution layer, you can look at how many filters are there and what is the filter size. For example, if the convolution size is 3x3 and number of filters is 64, number of parameters for that layer would be 576. For a fully connected layer, the number of weight parameters would be equal to the size of the previous layer times size of the current layer, e.g. 200x100, if previous layer's output is of size 200 and current layer has 100 hidden units. If the previous layer is a convolutional layer, the size of the previous layer would also depend on the size of the input image. Networks which have a fully connected layer take fixed size inputs, so the output size for the last convolutional layer can be computed based on the input size and other layer parameters http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/.

If there are bias parameters, you need to add number of filters which are there and number of fully connected layers. Pooling layers do not have weight parameters, so those can be ignored. Finally, you can multiply the size by 4, which is the size of float.